# How to achieve parallel execution using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, parallel-processing, selenium-chromedriver, task-parallel-library

We are facing a problem to achieve a parallel execution process using selenium c#.

We used the following technical stack,

**Automation** :Selenium

**Programming** : C#

**Driver** : Chrome

**Our current approach is,**

We have 5 pages and in each page have different actions to process. 
We are currently following Synchronous approach but it taking more time to complete the process.

We want to achieve this through parallel execution using selenium C#.

**We keep to maintain the following points while processing a each page.**

1. Open 5 tabs (Consider if your page count is 5) at a time and start process each individual page parallel.
2. Each page we have to valid both authentication and authorization.
3. Validate HTML DOM elements whether it is in removed?

Goal is to reduce the process completion time.

Thanks in advance.

Kindly help on this.

Comment: Can you specify what test framework you are using? NUnit supports parallel execution. There are also other parallel methods that do not use test framework attributes, if you want to go that route too.

Comment: Thanks @Christine. We want to implement without testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do parallel execution within the same chrome instance (with tabs). You must initialize a different instance of the chrome driver for every parallel instance.

This will open a different chrome instance for every run and then each will be able to execute. You would then need to dispose of each as it finishes.

Comment: Yes I agree. And here we want some sample code to try or even provide any source link for reference. Mainly to maintain Authorized user also not losing DOM elements.

Comment: By default the ChromeDriver will user the default profile so it would share any cookies. Normally this has a tendency to break things however. The tests in parallel will be unable to interact with each other, so if you have tasks on one page which are effecting another and you are testing that you will have to run in sequence.